# Asymptotic behaviour of $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^ndx $ as $n\to \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, asymptotics

I'd like to determine the asymptotic behaviour of $$\int_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx $$ as A) $n\to \infty $ with $0<f(x)\in \mathrm{C}^1([0,1]), 0\le x\le 1$
B) $n\to \infty $ with $0<f(x)\in \mathrm{C}^0([0,1]), 0\le x\le 1$

What I've already tried is expressing $x^n$ as $e^{n\ln x}$ then using substitution and  integration by parts so that I could obtain the major (dominant) contribution to the value of the integral but I'm not reaching anything meaningful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Naive first thought. Won't the limit be $0$ since that's what happens with just plain $x^n$? Do you need to know how fast it approaches $0$?

Comment: The limit is zero, so I'm assuming you need the dominant contribution to the integral. For that, use the fact that there exist constants $m,M>0$ with $m<f(x)<M$ on $[0,1]$. This tells you that $\frac{m}{n+1} \leq \int_0^1 f(x)x^ndx \leq \frac{M}{n+1}$. So the "rate of decay" is like $\frac 1{n+1}$.

Comment: Since the dominant part is near $x=1$, I would expect that replacing $f(x)$ with the constant function $f(1)$ should not change the value much, and that would give the integral as aymptotic to $\frac{f(1)}{n}$.  Probably, some variant of the argument from Laplace's method should be able to formalize this reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integration by parts works here: For $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ we have
$$ I_n \equiv \int \limits_0^1 f(x) x^n \mathrm{d} x = \frac{f(1)}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} \int \limits_0^1 f'(x) x^{n+1} \mathrm{d} x \, . $$
Since $f \in \mathrm{C}^1([0,1])$, we can estimate the remaining integral
according to
$$ \left\lvert \int \limits_0^1 f'(x) x^{n+1} \mathrm{d} x \right \rvert \leq \lVert f' \rVert_\infty \int \limits_0^1 x^{n+1} \mathrm{d} x = \frac{\lVert f' \rVert_\infty}{n+2} \, , \, n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \, . $$
This shows that
$$ I_n = \frac{f(1)}{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \, , \, n \to \infty \, , $$
as conjectured by Daniel Schepler in the comments.

We can't integrate by parts again, but we can still find the next term in the asymptotic expansion by computing
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \left[I_n - \frac{f(1)}{n}\right] &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[-\frac{n^2 f(1)}{n (n+1)} - \frac{n^2}{n+1} \int \limits_0^1 f'(x) x^{n+1} \mathrm{d} x\right] \\
&\!\!\!\!\!\overset{u = x^{n+1}}{=} - f(1) - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2} \int \limits_0^1 f'\left(u^{1/(n+1)}\right) u^{1/(n+1)} \mathrm{d} u \\
&= - f(1) - \int \limits_0^1 f'(1) \, \mathrm{d} u \\
&= - f(1) - f'(1) \, .
\end{align}
Here we used the continuity of $f'$ and the dominated convergence theorem. This implies
$$ I_n = \frac{f(1)}{n} - \frac{f(1)+f'(1)}{n^2} + \mathcal{o} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) $$
for $n \to \infty$.

Note that the assumption $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ is not needed (though for example the first term vanishes for $f(1) = 0$, of course).

Comment: Minor comment: if we have a remainder term with specified order (e.g., big-$\mathcal{O}$ or little-$o$), we use $=$ instead of $\sim$. Example: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  \sim \log n,\quad \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = \log n + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Comment: @Gary Good point, thanks! I have changed it.

Comment: Thank you so much, ComplexYetTrivial. What if $n\to \infty $ with $0<f(x)\in \mathrm{C}^0([0,1])$ ?

Comment: @DavidM. Then we cannot integrate by parts of course, but we can compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} n I_n$ directly (using the same change of variables as above). The result is $$ I_n = \frac{f(1)}{n} + \mathcal{o} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \, , $$ so we only get the leading term.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $f(x)\leq\max f$ and so $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)x^{n}dx\leq(\max f)\int_{0}^{1} x^{n}dx=(\max f)\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: You mean $\max(|f|)$.

Comment: The $f$ in question is positive.

Comment: Alright, thanks for noting. Shall I delete my comment?

Comment: Oh no need, what you said is also insightful.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous on a closed bounded interval, it has a maximum absolute value $M\ge0$ on that interval, so you have
$$
\left\vert \int_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx \right\vert \le \int_0^1 \left\vert f(x) x^n\right\vert \, dx \le M\int_0^1x^n\, dx = \frac M{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

To spice it up a bit:

We can use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to get
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)x^ndx =  \int_0^1 
 \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)x^n dx = \int_0^1 0 dx = 0.
$$
Here $f(x)x^n$ is dominated by the continuous and hence integrable function $f(x)$.

Technically for $x=1$ we get $f(1)$ as limit, but the equality above is still true since we are allowed to change the integrand on a null set.